# Fetching particular attributes or properties in CoreData

Tags: ios, core-data, ui-automation, swift3

i am using following Code to eliminate attributes while fetching from my CoreDataModel called industry. Still i am able to access those attributes which have not requested using **fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch**
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Industry")
        fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = ["id","industry_name"]

```
    After this i am using following code:
    industryObject.industry_name=tuple.value(forKey: ""ind_subtype"") as? String

    "ind_subtype" i have not specified in *.propertiesToFetch* and i am still able to access it


func fetchIndustryNamesWithId()->[IndustryData]{

        var industryData=[IndustryData]()
        //fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "firstName == %@", firstName)
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "Industry")
        fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = ["id","industry_name"]
        do {
            let tuples = try managedObjectContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
            for tuple in tuples{
                let industryObject=IndustryData()
                industryObject.id=tuple.value(forKey: "id") as? Int
                industryObject.industry_name=tuple.value(forKey: "industry_name") as? String
                industryObject.ind_subtype=tuple.value(forKey: "ind_subtype") as? String
                industryData.append(industryObject)
            }
            return industryData
        } catch {
            let fetchError = error as NSError
            print(fetchError)
        }
        return industryData
    }
```

Comment: please share your code

Comment: When you set the properties to fetch, it still fetches objects of type Industry, but will attempt to speed up the fetch by only getting the requested prorties on each object... which results in tuples = [Industry] not [(id, Industry_name)]

Comment: You can modify this behaviour by specifying the `resultType` for the fetch request as `.DictionaryResultType`, in which case the fetch returns an array of dictionaries (not tuples), with each dictionary having the keys specified in the `propertiesToFetch` and the corresponding attribute values.

Answer (score 0):

This is how it works. When you set `propertiesToFetch` CoreData will returns ManagedObject as a partially faulted. It means that some of the properties are populated some are not. When you access property that is not populated, core data will fulfil it for you but it probably will have performance impact because in most cases will require roundtrip to row cache.

For more info google for `CoreData Faulting`